# How to sort rows values and replace them by column names on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I would like to sort the values of each row and replace the values by column names.
Suppose we have the dataframe below.

```
ID   A    B    C
1    8    10   9
2    6    7    8
3    13   14   7
```

I want it to be converted to this form.

```
 1    B    C    A
 2    c    B    A
 3    B    A    C
```

Is there a way to do it in python?

I am thinking in something like this:

```
df.sort(0, ascending=False)
```

But it does not work for me.

Comment: Please show your efforts

Comment: I know it is complicated to do and that is why I asked. if there is a function to do it, then please advise, in case there is not a function like this, then I will develop a function to do it. So please advise instead of downvoting. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), but first get column `ID` to `index` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('ID')

print ((np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)))
[[1 2 0]
 [2 1 0]
 [1 0 2]]

print (df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)])
Index([['B', 'C', 'A'], ['C', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'A', 'C']], dtype='object')

print (pd.DataFrame(df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)], 
                               index=df.index))

    0  1  2
ID         
1   B  C  A
2   C  B  A
3   B  A  C    

print (pd.DataFrame(df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)], 
                               index=df.index).reset_index())

   ID  0  1  2
0   1  B  C  A
1   2  C  B  A
2   3  B  A  C
```

If need set columns from original `DataFrame`:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)], 
                               index=df.index,
                               columns=df.columns))

    A  B  C
ID         
1   B  C  A
2   C  B  A
3   B  A  C
```

**Timings**:

```
#[3 rows x 3 columns]

In [97]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)],index=df.index, columns=df.columns))
10000 loops, best of 3: 126 µs per loop

In [98]: %timeit (df.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values(ascending=False).index, axis=1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.95 ms per loop
```

---

```
#[30000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)    
#print (df)

df = df.set_index('ID')

In [103]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)],index=df.index, columns=df.columns))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 ms per loop

In [104]: %timeit (df.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values(ascending=False).index, axis=1))
1 loop, best of 3: 7.21 s per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to sort each row and take the resulting index.

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.sort_values(ascending=False).index, axis=1)
```

Note that when applying by row, the index of each row is the columns of the dataframe.